# Dependency Property not getting updated value via ActivityBind

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I have a Sequence Activity which holds two activities (Activity A and B), the input dependency property for Activity B is bound an output dependency property of Activity A. However, when I run the sequence activity, the Input for activity B is never updated and just uses the default value of activity A's output.

My question is: is there a way to enforce an update on activity B's input so that it gets the latest value of activity A's output?

Comment: I've Looked into this a bit more and still can't get it working, one thought was that the two activities are being run in two different execution contexts (AEC) so this may be why the bindings aren't working.